# struggling to create graph file in Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning

i am using below command to generate trained model file

```
    python tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py \
 --image_dir=/YourTrainImageFolder \
 —-output_graph=trainOut/hero_graph.pb \
 --output_labels=trainOut/hero_labels.txt \
 --summaries_dir=trainOut/summaries/ \
 --bottleneck_dir=trainOut/bottlenecks \
 --model_dir=trainOut/models/ \
 --saved_model_dir=trainOut/saveModelDir
```

It is generating all files except .pb file, i am following Tensorflow poets & 
https://medium.com/@elye.project/applying-tensorflow-in-android-in-4-steps-to-recognize-superhero-f224597eb055 tutorial

kindly help